# synchronize two win ce 6 devices using usb

Tags: synchronization, usb, windows-ce, activesync

I wanted to know if there is any way to synchronize (or exchanging files) two Windows CE 6.0 devices. Actually, I am able using ActiveSync to synchronize them one by one with a computer. Can I bypass the computer with plugging directly devices together and running a kind of ActiveSync Server in one of them (which will be the master)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's possible to make a wince device seen as a mass storage from another computer or another device (in my case another wince device).

You need to update you registry settings to:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers]
   "DefaultClientDriver"=- ; erase previous default
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers]
   "DefaultClientDriver"="Mass_Storage_Class"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\FunctionDrivers\Mass_Storage_Class]
    "Dll"="usbmsfn.dll"
    "InterfaceSubClass"=dword:06 
    "InterfaceProtocol"=dword:50 
   "DeviceName"="DSK1:" 
   "FriendlyName"="Mass Storage"
   "idVendor"=dword:045E
    "Manufacturer"="Generic Manufacturer (PROTOTYPE--Remember to change idVendor)"
    "idProduct"=dword:FFFF
    "Product"="Generic Mass Storage (PROTOTYPE--Remember to change idVendor)"
    "bcdDevice"=dword:0
```

This is the official documentation of the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895481.aspx

"usbmsfn.dll" should be also installed on your device to make this work.

Do not also forget to restart your device after registry modification,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing off-the-shelf that provides anything like this.  In fact few devices can even support this from a hardware perspective.  You'd either need USB OTG hardware support and the appropriate drivers for both, or a Host driver (and hardware) and a Client driver (and hardware) on the other.

Even if you had that, you would still need to write the application and conflict-resolution pieces.

It's probably (a lot) less work to just write an app to export and import the state info you want to transfer, and that could even be done over the network if they are network capable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply,

Both of them are USB OTG, so do you know where (and how) can I get the appropriate driver?

And I have also the host driver installed on them, because my two devices are able to mount a mass storage, so normally the host driver should be present. So where can I find the Client driver?